# cXML PunchOut Transaction and Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am researching how to PunchOut enable a webstore and from what I read, I have to use a server side language. Unfortunatly I am limited to only using Javascript. Can this be done? Does anyone have any best practices or can point me to a reference for enabling a PunchOut ecommerce store by only using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

According to the cXML Users Guide (http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLUsersGuide.pdf) on page 23 it states "PunchOut catalogs are made possible by Web server 
applications, written in a programming language such as ASP (Active Server Pages), 
JavaScript, or CGI (Common Gateway Interface), that manage buyers’ PunchOut 
sessions.".  Based on that it sounds possible as they call out JavaScript, but they also call out the fact that it is done by Web server applications. I have not used a strictly JavaScript myself, just ASP and recently .NET.

However, I'm not a JavaScript expert so YMMV.  The main thing to keep in mind that most punch-outs (especially from Ariba) will be initiated via an HTTP POST with the cXML document XML as a form value.  If you can use JavaScript to process that XML and send back a response without server side work, then you should be good to go.